# C++ Visual Studio weired behaviour of signed integer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, long-integer, signed

I have some long long constants for boundaries in my calculations. Now I have a weired behaviour because some conditions are not valid because the numbers are "missinterpreted"
The first output is the number I wantet to use....in the output you can see that the - sign is removed, so I thought about an underflow, but when I add a 0, so the number is even higher, the output is correct....

I'm using Visual studio 2012

```
cout<<-2147483648<<endl;
cout<<-2147483649<<endl;
cout<<-21474836480<<endl;
cout<<-21474836490<<endl;
cout<<-214748364800<<endl;
cout<<-214748364900<<endl;
```

as you can see, in the first 2 lines the - sign is removed

```
2147483648
2147483647
-21474836480
-21474836490
-214748364800
-214748364900
```

any Idea whats the problem here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Your example doesn't even compile in VS2012. It fails with the following error message for those 2 lines: `error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should carefully examine a warning messages your compiler gives to you. If your code produces no warnings, then you should increase warning generation level for your compiler. This code on MSVC compiler will produce two warnings:

> warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result
>   still unsigned

Which is basically means, that compiler will threat first two values as `unsigned int`, then apply to it unary minus operator. To solve this problem you should implicitly declare value type:

```
cout << -(long long)2147483649 << endl;
```

Comment: thx alot! I even have to do long long test=-(long long)2147483648

Comment: Where the `LL` suffix is probably the way to go (instead of the cast) and if you're on a recent compiler you can just do: `auto value = -214748364900LL;`

Answer (score 2):

Compiler warnings shall not be ignored !

As you do not suffix your integer litterals, the compiler uses `int` for values less than INT_MAX and `unsigned int` for values between INT_MAX and UINT_MAX. Assuming a 2 complement 32 bits platform, INT_MAX is 2147483647, so 2147483648 and 2147483648 are unsigned and as said by the warning, applying a minus sign to an unsigned type still gives a positive value. So the results are due to an overflow.

The correct way is to suffix the litteral with L for `long` and LL for `long long`:

```
cout<<-2147483648LL<<endl;
cout<<-2147483649LL<<endl;
cout<<-21474836480LL<<endl;
cout<<-21474836490LL<<endl;
cout<<-214748364800LL<<endl;
cout<<-214748364900LL<<endl;
```